# How to make the second line of numbers different from the first one?

Tags: java

So I need the second numbers always be different from the first line of numbers.

Don't know what to do

```
package kkas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class sdsdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          System.out.println("Laimīgie skaitļi:");

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<35; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Laimīgie skaitļi nr.2:");

        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<35; i++) {
            list2.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list2);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(list2.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that there can't be any numbers in common between the two lists? Or that the corresponding elements can't be equal? Or...?

Comment: The easiest way to do this might be simply to pick the first 5 numbers from the shuffled list as your first line, and the second 5 numbers from the same list (without reshuffling) as your second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct all found identical mappings by swapping the element with an other in the list.
At the other position that will be safe or even correcting too.

The only problem is that the other position must not be `i` itself.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 35; i++) {
        list2.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list2);
    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
        if (list2.get(i).equals(list.get(i))) {
            // Swap, exchange with another value:
            if (i > 0) {
                ... set with previous one at i-1 or 0
            } else { // For i == 0, we 
                ... set with size() -1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so this got me a little further, but my objective is for the second line of numbers(5 numbers), always to be different from the first line, like for example, first line of numbers are 23,4,5,16 and 25, they cant repeat in the second one

Comment: Ah, shuffle 10 or more, and pick `list.subList(0, 5)` and `(5, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something with a while for 2nd loop and apply a check on list size so that

1. Run a while loop till you reach ecpected size of list2
2. Check if iterated value already exist in list 1 or not

```
int i =0;
while(list2.getSize()<=5){
        if(!list.contains(i)){
               System.out.println(list2.get(i));
        }
        i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic use case for the traditional [`Iterator<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) of a `Collection`. First, generate your `List` of elements (I would use an `IntStream` myself). Then get the `iterator()` and then iterate with a single iterator the shuffled `Collection`. Since you have 34 elements, iterating 10 should be safe; still, I would further extract the printing logic to another method so you don't repeat yourself. Something like,

```
public static <E> void printN(Iterator<E> iter, String msg, int n) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    for (int i = 0; i < n && iter.hasNext(); i++) {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 35).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
    printN(iter, "Laimīgie skaitļi:", 5);
    printN(iter, "Laimīgie skaitļi nr.2:", 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By altering the second loop like this :

```
            List<Integer> subList = list.subList(0, 5);
            int k=0;
            for (int i=0; k<5 && !subList.contains(list2.get(i)); i++) {
                k++;
                System.out.println(list2.get(i));
            }
```